# Can't connect to MySql database on web hosting using C# Windows application?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to connect on some web hosting using C# Windows application, but unsuccessfuly.

I use this con string:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;
```

**I'm sure that values in con string are ok, because i have used this values in php connect script.**

Here is the test code:

```
 string conString = "Server=localhost;Database=********;Uid=********;Pwd=********;";
 MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conString);
 try
 {
    con.Open();
    MessageBox.Show("Connected!");
 }
 catch (MySqlException mex)
 {
   MessageBox.Show(mex.Message);
   con.Close();
 }
```

I have MySql connector installed, i have tried another port 3307, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: @Damith

"Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts!".

Comment: Are you able to connect to the db using some local mysql tool like mysql workbench or heidi?

Comment: @SumitGhosh

No, Failed Connection, i can to connect to local database on my pc, but i can't to connect on website host.

Comment: Then your db server is not accepting remote connections, it might be behind a firewall. Most companies like godaddy implement a firewall on there db servers, your best bet now is to your their internal web based phpmyadmin for database management.

Answer (score 0):

From here i used values in connection string:

[image: Values]